# How to search Chinese data

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, search, chinese-locale

I have an issues in my app user able to search Chinese data using search bar .i have tried all the ways like adding Chinese alphabets like this 'NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"诶比西迪伊艾弗吉艾尺艾杰艾勒艾马艾娜哦屁吉吾艾儿艾丝提伊吾维豆贝尔维艾克斯艾贼德!"]invertedSet]'but there is no luck .can any one please suggest me the proper way to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add more details, how data looks like? how exactly you perform search?